# Why is Jenkins not pulling in a browser?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, jenkins, continuous-integration

I installed Jenkins on my debian server. It is set on port 8080 and when I try connecting to it nothing happens. I know it is running because when I do:

```
root@jini01:/etc/default# /etc/init.d/jenkins restart
```

I get this back.

```
[ ok ] Restarting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server: jenkins.
```

Here is my jenkins config file:

```
# defaults for jenkins continuous integration server

# pulled in from the init script; makes things easier.
NAME=jenkins

# location of java
JAVA=/usr/bin/java

# arguments to pass to java
#JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx256m"
#JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" # make jenkins listen on IPv4 address

PIDFILE=/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid

# user id to be invoked as (otherwise will run as root; not wise!)
JENKINS_USER=jenkins

# location of the jenkins war file
JENKINS_WAR=/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war

# jenkins home location
JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins

# set this to false if you don't want Hudson to run by itself
# in this set up, you are expected to provide a servlet container
# to host jenkins.
RUN_STANDALONE=true

# log location.  this may be a syslog facility.priority
JENKINS_LOG=/var/log/jenkins/$NAME.log
#HUDSON_LOG=daemon.info

# OS LIMITS SETUP
#   comment this out to observe /etc/security/limits.conf
#   this is on by default because http://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/2fb288474e980d0e7ff9c4a3b768874835$
#   reported that Ubuntu's PAM configuration doesn't include pam_limits.so, and as a result the # of file
#   descriptors are forced to 1024 regardless of /etc/security/limits.conf
MAXOPENFILES=8192

# port for HTTP connector (default 8080; disable with -1)
HTTP_PORT=8080

# port for AJP connector (disabled by default)
AJP_PORT=-1

# servlet context, important if you want to use apache proxying
PREFIX=/jenkins

# arguments to pass to jenkins.
# --javahome=$JAVA_HOME
# --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT (default 8080; disable with -1)
# --httpsPort=$HTTP_PORT
# --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT
# --argumentsRealm.passwd.$ADMIN_USER=[password]
# --argumentsRealm.passwd.$ADMIN_USER=[password]
# --argumentsRealm.$ADMIN_USER=admin
# --webroot=~/.jenkins/war
# --prefix=$PREFIX
```

When I do :

```
ps aux | grep -i java
```

I get:

```
root     12912  0.0  0.0   7676   892 pts/0    S+   19:04   0:00 grep -i java
```

Why will it not show up on a browser even when i specify the 8080 port?

Comment: Blocked by firewall? What is the output of # iptables --list Are you coming in from localhost, or outside?

Comment: libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-index.c:816 index_mm_open: magic check fail: b007fa57 instead of b007f457
iptables v1.4.13: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

Comment: I am coming from outside

Comment: do you have anything else running on that box?  Maybe published through apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `telnet <server-ip> 8080`. If nothing happens it means you have a firewall blocking that port

Comment: ```telnet jenkins-prod 8080                                                                                                [12:15:02] production
Trying x.x.x.x...
Connected to jenkins-prod.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`$ /sbin/sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only`

If this value is 1 you need to disable the setting:

`$ sudo /sbin/sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only=0`

For a persistent fix:
check `/etc/sysctl.conf` and `/etc/sysctl.d/*` for this setting and restart after changing it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some line at the end of your file (/etc/default/jenkins) like

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT"
JENKINS_ARGS="$JENKINS_ARGS  --prefix=$PREFIX"
```